# How to tell ruby net libraries to use a particular network interface?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm doing some page scraping for a client and need to connect to their
vpn server.  So I have the vpn client running on my linux box, and this
creates a new interface, say ppp0. Now, when I run Mechanize/open-uri,
etc. I need to be able to bind specifically to this particular
interface, because the other interfaces are to the internet in general.
How do I do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If what you are connecting to over the VPN isn't also available over the open internet you shouldn't have to do anything and the internal TCP/IP networking stack should sort out the correct interface automatically.

Comment: Thanks, but it times out.  There are 8 interfaces, so perhaps it goes through each of them and then times out - not sure.  In any case, it doesn't connect.